# Does WebClient follow Location headers when getting a 201 response?

Tags: .net, rest, redirect, webclient

Does the .NET WebClient follow the *Location* header which should be sent together with a `201 Created` response? If yes, is there a way to disable it?

Additionally I'm looking for a way to retrieve the value of the Location header as I'd like to display the link of the created resource to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked the .NET framework sourcecode and here's the answer:
WebClient uses HttpWebRequest which uses the following logic for following redirects:

```
else if (AllowAutoRedirect && (
    ResponseStatusCode==HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous          || // 300
    ResponseStatusCode==HttpStatusCode.Moved              || // 301
    ResponseStatusCode==HttpStatusCode.Redirect           || // 302
    ResponseStatusCode==HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod     || // 303
    ResponseStatusCode==HttpStatusCode.RedirectKeepVerb ))   // 307
{
```

The value of the *Location* header is in the `ResponseHeaders` collection of the WebClient (or the event args when using async).